# Wordpress Word Count to exclude shortcodes?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a function that gets the overall word count within a post.

```
function ic_word_count() {
    global $post;

    $ic_content = strip_tags(  $post->post_content );
    $ic_stripped = strip_shortcodes($ic_content);
    return $ic_stripped;
}
```

I'm trying to get it to exclude all shortcodes, so basically exclude anything with square brackets and everything in between them. For example exclude `[shortcode]` or `[This Shortcode]`

Any idea on how I could add that part to the above function?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a handy function, strip_shortcodes. Codex details here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes

Your function uses `$post->ID` but you aren't getting the global post value.

Finally you already have access to the post content inside the global $post object so just use that instead of get_post_field.

E.g. `global $post;`

```
function ic_word_count() {
    global $post;

    $wc_content = $post->post_content;
    $ic_word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( strip_shortcodes( $wc_content ) ) );

    return $ic_word_count;
}
```

A smaller version:

```
function ic_word_count() {
    global $post;

    return str_word_count( strip_tags( strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content ) ) );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a word count of 0 when I add that snippet in there.

Comment: Just to confirm you are still assigning the result to a variable. I'll update my answer to make this clear btw. If so please add the following line of code and let me know if there's anything output.

`echo strip_tags( strip_shortcodes( $wc_content ) );`

Comment: I did assign it to a variable still.  I'm echoing the entire function, so I'm still getting a 0 count with this `<?php echo ic_word_count(); ?>`

Comment: I wasn't asking you to echo the entire function. I wanted to see the output when you echo the content itself after the modifications have been run. The content rather than the count. For good measure please echo `$wc_content` as well. We need to be sure valid content is found and being run through.

Comment: Please be aware of a new modification made to my answer. I'll update the answer with an explanation in a moment.

Comment: No words are appearing when I echo the content itself.  I tried both of the revised scripts.

Comment: Interesting. Where are you trying to use the function?

Comment: The function is set in my functions.php file, but the count and data is being displayed on a post/page edit screen.

Comment: If you remove the strip_shortcodes() part of the function, it outputs the stripped tag text fine...it dosent make sense.